# Marking Your Python Program as High DPI Aware Seamlessly Windows

Tags: python, graphics, operating-system, dpi, winreg

I just wanted to share the best way I found to do this in case other people were having issues as I was. If your Python/Kivy program has graphic issues with Virtual DPI scaling try this code out. It'll mark the program as High DPI Aware for you or the end user without having to do anything. This works for Windows 10, not sure about 8 or 7. Was wondering if anyone else knows if this will work for 8 and 7. To test this out, add the code in, set DPI up, log out and back in of user so the registry marks the DPI change, and run your code from SHELL. Your program should be DPI aware now!

```
import winreg
from os import path as ospath
from os import execl as osexecl
from sys import executable as sysex
from sys import argv as sysargv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None,winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    key = winreg.OpenKey(reg, r"Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics")
    print(winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'AppliedDPI'))
    filefound=True
    if winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'AppliedDPI')[0]!=96:
        key.Close()
        key = winreg.OpenKey(reg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

        ##If testing from SHELL also add these values into registry. This is not needed for complied EXEs. Make sure the path is correct or it won't work.

        winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'C:\python35\pythonw.exe', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'HIGHDPIAWARE')
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'C:\python35\python.exe', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'HIGHDPIAWARE')

        ##If Testing from SHELL change YOUREXE.exe to YOURPYFILE.py, otherwise it should be the name of your compiled EXE.

        exepath=str(ospath.abspath('YourEXE.exe'))
        try:
            winreg.QueryValueEx(key, exepath)
        except:
            print('FileNotFound')
            winreg.SetValueEx(key, exepath, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'HIGHDPIAWARE')
            print(winreg.QueryValueEx(key, exepath))
            filefound=False
    print(filefound)
    key.Close()
    reg.Close()

    ##If DPI Scaling was detected and program marked in registry, restart program. This will work in SHELL and your compiled EXE, not IDLE.

    if filefound==False:
        print('Restarting')
        python = sysex
        osexecl(python, python, * sysargv)
    else:
        YourApp().run()
```

Comment: Question: if I'm using Tkinter to create a GUI for different-sized monitors (same resolutions), does this 'High DPI Aware' code apply to the exe generated in Spyder(3.2.8)/Python(3.5.2) so that the GUI looks the same on a physically-larger monitor?