# DPI Awareness for Python program and Pyside2/Qt5 on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt5, tablet, dpi, pyside2

I've been working with Python 3.7 (Anaconda) and Pyside2, and all has been well.  However, in going to a Microsoft Surface tablet, the scaling of the display leads to distorted output (bunched text, etc.)  This is when the resolution is 2736x1824 and size of text is 200%.   If you set the resolution to 1600x900 and setting the size to 100%, you can get the GUI program to appear OK.

There is a link about making python and pythonw high DPI aware, but I'm always a bit nervous about running code that affects the registry.  I'm wondering how to do this manually:

[Marking Your Python Program as High DPI Aware Seamlessly Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401709/marking-your-python-program-as-high-dpi-aware-seamlessly-windows)

I've set python.exe and pythonw.exe (via Windows - Properties - Compatibility - Change high DPI settings, check the 'Use this setting to fix scaling problems'), but no dice.

Microsoft's commentary is here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025083/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices

But I don't know if there are any better ways of handling Qt5/Pyside2 graphics when this situation exists.

The workaround is OK, but not ideal.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47723454/6622587

Comment: Solved!  Thanks.   Wish I could have found that answer; I was searching under DPI, not "high resolution".