# How can I get correct Rectangular-area screenshots in different display scales on windows in Python？

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When the display scale is not 100%, using the PIL will get a screenshot with offset.
I want to know what can I do to get the correct screenshot in  Windows when display scale is not 100%
This is the PIL code

```
screenShot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
screenShot.show()
```

If can use PIL or pyside to achieve the effect, it is the best to me. Thx.

Comment: Use [`QScreen.grabWindow(0)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you saying your x1,y1,x2,y2 coordinates are incorrect?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/25467288/5987 is any help.